# Load N records from database in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to load only 5 elements from a list without loading all the list. I have these two entities:

```
public class Company
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public String Name{ get; set; }
   public List<Employee> EmployeeList{ get; set; }       
}
```

and:

```
public class Employee
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public String Name{ get; set; }       
}
```

I need to load only the last 5 records of the Employee for a company named "CompanyName".

I tried to use :

```
Company companySearch =systemDB.Companies
                               .Include("EmployeeList").Take(5)
                               .Where(d => d.Name.Equals("CompanyName"))
                               .SingleOrDefault();
```

But this code loads all the list and after gives me back only the last 5 records. I need a faster query.

PS: It's code first EF

Comment: Have you checked what queries are getting fired by entity framework to the database through sql query profiler tool?

Comment: eager loading returns all data - you must use projections

Comment: `d` variable in your lambda expression `d => d.Name.Equals("CompanyName")` corresponds to company class. Company class doesn't even have the `Name` property.

Comment: Agree with @tmg - unless you've turned off lazy loading on your db context, you would not be getting all records back. Perhaps you need an index on the table, so using Profiler to review the SQL query should show the `TOP 5` and `WHERE` in which you could design your index from.

Comment: @RBT yes I forgot the name property in copying the code

Answer (score 2):

For loading selective N records of `EmployeeList` you will have to have some criterion based on which the members of your collection navigation property will be filtered. I've taken that criterion as value of `ID` property of `Employee` entity. Here are all the steps required along with code snippet which will do the lazy loading of `EmployeeList` collection for `Company` entity

1. Enable lazy loading in constructor of your inherited dbContext class. I believe systemDB is object of a class which inherits from `DbContext`

   ```
   public SystemDB()
   {
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
   }
   ```
2. Remove the include clause to avoid eager loading:

   `Company companySearch =systemDB.Companies
                                  .Where(d => d.Name.Equals("CompanyName"))
                                  .SingleOrDefault();`

After execution of this line of code, If you check the `EmployeeList` property of `companySearch` object it will be shown as `Null` in quick watch window.

3. Perform the lazy loading of `EmployeeList` property using the below mentioned call. Put explicit criterion for filtering the records. I've the set the filter criteria to restrict the employees whose ID lies between 1 and 5, both boundaries being inclusive.

   `db.Entry<Company>(companySearch).Collection(s => s.EmployeeList).Query().Where(p => p.ID >= 1 && p.ID <= 5).Load();`

Answer (score 1):

> Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related entities. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj574232.aspx)

You could still try anonymous projection without lazyloading

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Anonymous projection.

```
Company companySearch =systemDB.Companies
                           .Where(d => d.Name.Equals("CompanyName"))
                           .Select(x=> new 
                           {
                              company = x,
                              employees = x.Employees.Take(5),
                           }
                           .FirstOrDefault()
```

You will get more idea about how to do anonymous projection is [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)